# ListView not showing items properly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm creating an app to fetch names of txt files from phone.I fetched all data into an arraylist and added it to the adapter. But problem is that listview not showing items properly.At first, only the first item shows up and as I scroll up and down more items appear.Although I have added a static image in the row item and that is shown properly,even I'm able to get file name in toast message on listview for items whose name is not visible that time. I'm posting my code check it and tell what's wrong

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private File sdcardObj=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
private ArrayList<String> filelist=new ArrayList<String>();
private ListView list;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listfiles);
    LongOperation longOperation=new LongOperation();
    longOperation.execute();

}
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        listFiles(sdcardObj,filelist);
        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        MyListAdapater myListAdapater=new MyListAdapater(MainActivity.this,filelist);
        list.setAdapter(myListAdapater);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
      progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait.Loading files list");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);

        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
private void listFiles(File sdcard,ArrayList<String> filelist) {
    if(sdcard.isDirectory()){
        File[] files = sdcard.listFiles();

        try {
            for (File f : files){
                if(!f.isDirectory()) {
                    if(f.getName().endsWith(".txt")|| f.getName().endsWith(".docx")||f.getName().endsWith(".rtf")) {
                        // Log.d(" FILES",f.getName());
                        this.filelist.add(f.getAbsolutePath());

                    }
                }
                else {
                    this.listFiles(f,this.filelist);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView cardId;

}

class MyListAdapater extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String>files=new ArrayList<>();
    LayoutInflater inflater ; Context context;
    public MyListAdapater(Context context,ArrayList<String> cardListForDisplay) {
        super();

        this.files = cardListForDisplay;
        this.context=context;

    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return files.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = view;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(rowView==null){
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            inflater = ((MainActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder.cardId=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
         //   /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.gameloft.android.ANMP.GloftFWHM/files/d_o_w_n_l_o_a_d_e_d.txt
        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            String name=files.get(arg0).substring(files.get(arg0).lastIndexOf("/")+1,files.get(arg0).length());
            holder.cardId.setText(name);
            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,files.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not showing properly`? it is wrongly positioned? resized or not showing at all?

Comment: Your code is way too long to post here. Have you tried to debug?

Comment: told you showing list size properly but the textview with file name doesn't shows up for all items .At start only for first item and as I scroll up and down it shows up for more items randomly

Comment: yes I am able to see file path for every item in toast

Comment: I recommend you use an ArrayAdapter instead of a BaseAdapter. That will solve most of the problems I immediately see.

Comment: Also, do not set the list `onItemClickListener` inside of `getView` That is making a circular reference to the list from each item everytime a list item is initialized. Please move that to `onCreate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, you are setting the data in your `else` case. So when the `if` case evaluate as `true`, there won't be any data set and your list view will show an empty row. Change the `getView` method like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View rowView = view;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(rowView==null)
    {
        holder   = new ViewHolder();
        inflater = ((MainActivity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        rowView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder.cardId=(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        rowView.setTag(holder);
     }
     holder      = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
     String name = files.get(arg0).substring(files.get(arg0).lastIndexOf("/")+1,files.get(arg0).length());
     holder.cardId.setText(name);
     return rowView;
}
```